How do I use CzmlDataSource in React Resium?
I'm trying to display a local czml file's contents on a map with React, Typescript and Resium. For some reason it keeps throwing the error This object was destroyed, i.e., destroy() was called. What am i doing wrong?
Here is the code:
function App() {
  const position = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-74.0707383, 40.7117244, 100);
  const pointGraphics = { pixelSize: 10 };

  return (
    <Viewer full>
       <Entity position={position} point={pointGraphics} />
       <CameraFlyTo destination={Cartesian3.fromDegrees(20.483, 47.860, 6000)}></CameraFlyTo>
       <CzmlDataSource data={'paths/lne.czml'}></CzmlDataSource>
    </Viewer>
  );
}

export default App;

The paths is in the public folder, I've already tried ./paths and /paths, with the same error. I also have the access token, but I deleted it from this codesnippet. Based on the Resium website, it should be used like this.

You should move the declaration of the position and pointGraphics variables outside the App function.
Declaring them inside the App function causes them to  re-initialize whenever the component re-renders that's why you're getting the error:
This object was destroyed, i.e., destroy()
Do it like this instead:
//Code from the Resium website:
import { Viewer, Entity } from "resium";
import { Cartesian3 } from "cesium";

const position = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-74.0707383, 40.7117244, 100);
const pointGraphics = { pixelSize: 10 };

function App() {
  return (
    <Viewer full>
      <Entity position={position} point={pointGraphics} />
    </Viewer>
  );
}

export default App;

Let me know if that helps or if you have any other questions.

Hi! I tried your solution, and unfortunately, i'm still getting the same error. It works perfectly fine, when i remove the CzmlDataSource element, but as soon as i put it back, it keeps throwing the object was destroyed error.

Could you create a reproducible example of your code on code sandbox maybe or publish the existing code on GitHub?

I created a github repo and uploaded the code. I replaced the czml files with an example because the ones i'm working with are not mine. The problem still occurs with this file too: https://github.com/vakics/help-with-resium

I've checked out the project and ran it locally and I see the issue. It's tricky to fix. Have you tried to raise an issue on the Resium GitHub repository?

Not yet, i hoped that the issue is fixable without getting them involved. But i will, thank you!
